# Go to default route from any URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

### Current Route

---

```
// Create the front-end route.
Route defaultRoute = routes.MapRoute(
    "CMS_Default",
    "CMS/RenderMvc/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "RenderMvc", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
defaultRoute.RouteHandler = new RenderRouteHandler(cmsContext, ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory());
```

### Desired Functionality

---

I would like any URL to be picked up e.g. `/home`, `/about-us`, `/contact-us` and go to the current route above: `/cms/rendermvc/home`, `/cms/rendermvc/about-us`, `/cms/rendermvc/contact-us` as this is were it will take the URL segment or in the routes case the `{action}` and do the logic for getting the content from the database. I would like to do this **without** the use of a default `{*url}` route.

### Current Ideas

---

- <s>I'm not very familiar with it but could `ActionFilters` be used in this instance?</s>
- I believe this could be achieved by a default module?

### Desired Functionality Examples

---

[Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/Request-Pipeline/) has the identical routing structure I am after, just with a lot more complexity.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying here?

Comment: @DavidG when I go to the `/home` url I want this default route action to fire. It does not do this unless I go to `/cms/rendermvc/index`.

Comment: I want my routing to be very similar if not the same (with less complexity) to Umbraco. I have been crawling through their source code but cannot figure out how they are able to redirect `/home` to `/umbraco/rendermvc/index` and then back to `/home` unless I'm going about it all wrong?

Comment: You have two options. First, you can write other routes eg. Home, and set the controller and action to your default action. I mean you have to write every possible routing you want to address to the default route.
2nd option is using rewrite url

Comment: @Mahdi the default route: `/cms/rendermvc/{url}` will handle every front-end page e.g. `Home`, `About`, `Contact`. The content and logic for these pages are handled in the `RenderMvcController`. I'm not entirely sure how I would rewrite `/home` to go to the controller action and then back to the provided url. As I do not want a route like this: `{url}`

Comment: What I would like is for any url to be picked up and then go to the `RenderMvcController` route without the use of a `{url}` route.

Comment: I believe the question is a bit more complex that it seems.

Comment: vice versa I think is easier than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, as my question suggests I needed a `IHttpModule`. With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249948/mvc-custom-routing-only-for-get-requests), I have now been able to get my desired routing!

For those of you that are curious, here is my code.

### CMSModule

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class CMSModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var httpContext = ((HttpApplication) sender).Context;
            BeginRequest(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
        };
    }

    private void BeginRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        Uri url = httpContext.Request.Url;
        string requestExtension = Path.GetExtension(url.LocalPath);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestExtension)) return;

        httpContext.RewritePath("/cms/rendermvc" + httpContext.Request.Path);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    { }
}
```

### Web.config

---

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="CMSModule" type="CMS.Web.CMSModule,CMS.Web"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### WARNING

---

This is very basic code and I would not suggest copying it as I'm sure there are lots of edge cases that I'm not taking into account but for the moment, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another route to your routeTable. for example :

```
Route HomeRoute = routes.MapRoute(
    "CMS_Home",
    "CMS/Home",
    new { controller = "RenderMvc", action = "HomeAction"}
);

Route AboutRoute = routes.MapRoute(
    "CMS_About",
    "CMS/About",
    new { controller = "RenderMvc", action = "About"}
);
```

So all these routes will address to RenderMvcController and different action.

Comment: Hi Mahdi, thank you for the suggestion. However I'm not sure you understand the question. I would like to do this **WITHOUT** the use of more routes. As the URL should be sent over to the default one. Please view my updated answer, which hopefully explains the question a bit better.

Comment: This routing is not used for the CMS, that will be routed through AngularJS. This route is purely for getting the provided URL passing it to the custom `RouteHandler` which will then get content e.g. `Name`, `Id`, `Alias`, `Template` from the database using the URL that was provided and rendering the default view with this information.

Comment: I don't get it so. what's wrong with this routing : "CMS/RenderMvc/{url}",
    new { controller = "RenderMvc", action = "Index", url = UrlParameter.Optional }
and you can get url parameter in index action.

Comment: For one, this route would only be fired when you go to this url: `cms/rendermvc/home`. I would like it to happen from any given url. I have updated my question with an example of software with an almost identical routing system.

Comment: It will work for all routes, because {url} is an optional parameter

Comment: check this question maybe it's helpful for your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026441/dynamic-routes-from-database-for-asp-net-mvc-cms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225702/discussion-between-halden-collier-and-mahdi-farhani).

Comment: I was able to find my own answer, check it out if you're curious.

Comment: Mark your post as answer

Comment: I can't until tomorrow